# Averages and squares: is this true, and if yes, how to prove it?

Tags: proof-writing, average

I have come across an expression looking like this:
$$a^2-\langle a^2 \rangle =-(b^2-\langle b^2 \rangle)$$
Where the edged parentheses are for averages. a and b are some functions. Is it true then, that (either in general or under some circumstance - like a and b be periodic with the same frequency, which they in my specific case happen to be):
$$a-\langle a \rangle =-(b-\langle b \rangle)$$

How to either prove or disprove it? It might be very easy, but I have managed to get myself confused here

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging your condition gives $a^2 + b^2 = \langle a^2 + b^2 \rangle$, from which it follows that $a^2 + b^2$ must be constant.

So let's take, for example, $a = \cos \theta, b = \sin \theta$, and I'll assume that the averages here mean averages over a period. Here $\langle a \rangle = \langle b \rangle = 0$, so $a - \langle a \rangle = \cos \theta \neq b - \langle b \rangle = \sin \theta$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Could it possibly make any difference, if I demand a and b to always be greater than zero?

Comment: @Malthe: no. You can take, for example, $a$ to be a sawtooth wave, say $a(x) = x$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ and repeating with period $1$, and $b(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ and repeating with period $1$. Then $a$ is piecewise linear but $b$ is not so there's no way we can have $a - \langle a \rangle = b - \langle b \rangle$. What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: The motivation is, that the first equation is something that must be true in a certain physical system. And it seems to behave in way, that the second equation should always be either true or false, even though the system can behave in quite a few different ways.

Comment: But since it is a physical system, a and b (which in this case are lengths of a spring) must be greater than zero, and they must follow a continuous and smooth path. I wondered if one could make some general mathematical proofs about this, but maybe it would fit better in a physics forum.

Comment: Well, I already gave you a counterexample, and it can be modified into a smooth counterexample with very little difficulty.